# run form action on asp page

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

Is it possible to perform a traditional form action from a classic .asp page?

This app I'm working on uses a form-to-email gateway (for which I can't view the source)

```
<form method="post" action="http://xxxx:7462/forms/7">
[FORM FIELDS HERE]
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

That xxxx:7462/forms/7 action sends the fields to a mail gateway which sends an email to someone and redirects to a page called thankyou.asp

The problem is that it takes a long time to go the thankyou.asp and we need it to go immediately. Is it possible to store the form information and call this action from the thankyou.asp page?

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form from thankyou.asp using javascript/jquery.  First Post the data to thankyou.asp and then grab the form fields and insert them into the jquery post

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {field1: <%=request.form("field1").value%>, field2: <%=request.form("Field2").value%>,etc...},
        url: "http://xxxx:7462/forms/7",
        success: function() {
            //do whatever here after it's done processing
            alert("Email Sent");
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in classic ASP using the serverXMLHTTP object, which is part of MSXML.DLL, present on any modern Windows system.

Microsoft describes how to use it here (POST and GET, and dealing with results):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766431(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps,

Erik